# printed NONE while using np.fill_diagona for matrix while filling digonal with 0?

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to np.fill_dagonl(x,0) in the below matrix

```
array([[1.        , 1.        , 1.        , ..., 1.        , 1.        ,
    1.        ],
   [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , ..., 1.        , 0.98344802,
    1.        ],
   [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , ..., 1.        , 1.        ,
    1.        ],
   ...,
   [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , ..., 1.        , 1.        ,
    1.        ],
   [1.        , 0.98344802, 1.        , ..., 1.        , 1.        ,
    1.        ],
   [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , ..., 1.        , 1.        ,
    1.        ]])
```

When I print it shows none. Someone tell me why and how to correct it.

The matrix size is 1862*1862.

Comment: Please share your code with an example (perhaps a smaller one, because it probably has the same issue) that shows the behaviour that you're asking about. You only shared (part of) the definition of an array - there's nothing here that would print anything and it's unclear how you apply that function to the array.

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fill_diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) operates on its argument *in place*, and returns None.

I suspect you did something like

```
x = np.fill_diagonal(x, 0)
```

which set `x` to None, because that is what `fill_diagonal` returned.  Change that to

```
np.fill_diagonal(x, 0)
```

Then when you print `x`, you'll see that is has been changed.